# AWS Cloudwatch: How to monitor a specific S3 object upload frequency

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

I am looking to troubleshoot an IoT device to test how consistently it uploads a certain object to S3. Specifically, the device uploads an object to `s3://mybucket/myprefix/filename.json`. The IoT device should upload this file every 60 seconds without fail, so I'm looking to be able to eventually extract e.g. a CSV with timestamps for each ObjectCreated event for that object so that I can plot the deltas in the timestamps.

I assume the right solution involves CloudWatch, but it seems like e.g. creating an Event trigger only lets me trigger e.g. a Lambda function or similar. I am looking for something lighter.

Is this possible to set up in the CloudWatch section directly or how would one go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up a data plane trail on CloudTrail for that.

This code is copied from [CloudTrail docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/logging-data-events-with-cloudtrail.html#creating-data-event-selectors-advanced) with minor modifications:

```
aws cloudtrail put-event-selectors --trail-name TrailName \
--advanced-event-selectors 
'[
  {
    "Name": "Problematic IOT",
    "FieldSelectors": [
      { "Field": "eventCategory", "Equals": ["Data"] },
      { "Field": "resources.type", "Equals": ["AWS::S3::Object"] },
      { "Field": "eventName", "Equals": ["PutObject""] },
      { "Field": "resources.ARN", "Equals": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/myprefix/filename.json"] }
    ]
  }
]'
```